# Why isn't __dict__ a callable

Tags: python, django, django-models

Why are `__dict__` and for example `__unicode__` not both callable or the other way around?

Django tells me to set a unicode return as a method on an Model, for example:

```
class Obj(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'hey'

>>> x = Obj()
<__main__.Obj object at 0x100703e10>
>>> x.__unicode__()
u'hello'
>>> x.__dict__
{}
```

It seems an odd discrepancy, can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: You are confusing attribute names with being callable. The two are not connected. `.__unicode__` is an attribute, and it resolves to a method that you can call. `.__dict__` is an attribute, and it resolves to a dictionary. Both use the a *naming convention*, double underscores around names signals that the name is reserved, and has special meaning.

Comment: I don't understand the question. `__unicode__` is a method that is called whenever you want a unicode representation of an object. `__dict__` is an attribute containing all the members of an object. What is your issue?

Comment: I know what methods and attributes are, I am wondering why there's a style difference, hence the double underscore and doesn't dict operate some magic like a method does, instead of simply holding a dict, I mean the dict has to be ccalculated somehwere?

Comment: @user2378079: `__dict__` is reserved and its value is usually calculated by Python itself, although you can override it. There is no style difference, everything is fine here. Furthermore take a look at other "magic" methods like `__delattr__`, `__format__`, `__getattribute__`, `__hash__`, `__init__`, `__new__` etc., as well as other attributes like `__class__`, `__doc__`, `__module__` etc. Why do you insist on having only callable or non-callable attributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `__foo__` convention is used for both methods and non-callable attributes in Python. `__unicode__` is a method, `__dict__` is not.

Comment: Ok so both are ok, that explains. Well not really on topic, but how and where is __dict__ calculated?

Comment: Assigning to an attribute on an object is just syntatic sugar for setting the attribute in its ```__dict___```.

Comment: @user2378079: I suppose at object creation, but it might depend on the type of object. E.g. a class's `__dict__` is actually a `dict_proxy` object, not really a `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

`__dict__` is the dictionary of the instance, not a method.

Comment: Hi. Please don't approve [suggested edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2114868) without seeing changes.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: See the second table. The suggester completely changed the expected output